# Making a Python script into a file that's easy to open for other users

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, exe, qr-code

I wrote a Python script that generates a QR Code containing the user's contact information, and now I can't find a solid way to deliver it to the users. This is made for a group of people with no programming knowledge, so I need to make it very simple. I used tkinter to make a window in which the user can input their data, and then the QR code is generated in their Downloads folder.

My first thought was to make a .exe file using auto-py-to-exe, which worked on my machine, but didn't work on someone else's for some strange reason (they simply couldn't open it, not even a dialogue box appeared giving a reason why).

I'm running out of ideas here, open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: Running the `exe` from cmd might give some insight as to why it wouldn't open, then also logging stuff is possible. Maybe (likely) an issue with some paths.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple streamlit app.

If your code can be public, you can push it to github and deploy it from there. It's free and should be straight forward.